# Backbone not returning data though sent from backend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

I am trying to fetch data from the backend in backbone and though the data is returned to the frontend, the success function is not executing at all but doing console.log() on done gives out all the data fetched from the backend.

```
 var app = app || {};
    app.url = '/usernotes/';

    app.AboutModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function() {
            return app.url;
        },
        defaults: {
            about: 'No',
            editorNote: ''

        },
        set: function() {
          localStorage.setItem('about', JSON.stringify(this.toJSON()));
        }
    });

app.AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#aboutParent',

        events: {
            'click #yes': 'GetData',
            'click #no': 'Default',
            'click #custom': 'OpenEditor'
        },

        template: _.template($('#about').html()),

        initialize: function() {            
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template, this);
        },

        Default: function() {
            this.model.set({
                about: 'No'
            });            
        },

        GetData: function() {            
            this.model = new app.AboutModel({});

            app.email = $('#data-user').text();
            app.username = $('#data-username').text();

            this.model.fetch({
                data: {
                    email: app.email,
                    username: app.username
                },
                type: 'POST',
                processData: true,
                success: function(data) {                                                         
                    $('.summernote .note-editable').html(data.attributes.about);
                },complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                },
                error: function() {                                                   
                    $('.summernote .note-editable').html('');
                }

            });

        }

    });
```

This is how it looks in the express backend

```
exports.find = function(req, res) {

if (req.body === null || req.body === undefined) {
    res.send(null);
} else {        
    req.app.db.models.UserNotes.findOne({
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {                
            res.send({
                "error": "The Email Does not exist in the database"
            });
        } else {                
            res.send(user);
        }
    });

}
```

};[image]

Comment: There is a lot going on here that doesn't look quite right.  Where are you creating an instance of your view?  Do you really need to create a new instance of the model for every GetData call?  Why not just instantiate one instance of the model and then have the view listen to it for changes?  Just as a guess I'd say your GetData function is finishing (and thus the newly created model is gone) long before the callback gets called.

Comment: Thanks, i will instantiate the model on initializing the view, I didnt realize that part, maybe that is where my code is going wrong.